# Cannot get a list of resources from folder

Tags: android, android-resources

I've got some folders in my res folder.
I need to dynamically get a list of their names.

when I use

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
list = assetManager.list("/");
```

I get a list, containing:

```
AndroidManifest.xml
META_INF
assets
classes.dex
res
resources.arsc
```

But when I use any of this:

```
assetManager.list("/res");
or
assetManager.list("res");
or
assetManager.list("/res/");
```

I get an empty list.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please Try this 
 `String[] allFilesInPackage = this.getResources().getAssets().list("");`